# How to create folder for generated sources in Maven?

Tags: maven-2, jax-ws, wsimport

I have to generate sources using wsimport and i assume that it should go to /target/generated-sources/wsimport rather than /src/main/java.

The problem is that wsimport needs target folder created before execution and it fails. Can I create that dir first using any maven plugin. I can do it using ant but i prefer to keep it in POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to generate sources using wsimport and i assume that it should go to /target/generated-sources/wsimport rather than /src/main/java.

This is a correct assumption.

> The problem is that wsimport needs target folder created before execution and it fails. Can I create that dir first using any maven plugin. I can do it using ant but i prefer to keep it in POM.

I never noticed this problem (and would consider it as a bug, a plugin has to take care of such things).

The weird part is that [`WsImportMojo`](https://jax-ws-commons.dev.java.net/source/browse/jax-ws-commons/tags/jaxws-maven-plugin-1.12/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxws/WsImportMojo.java?rev=826&view=markup) seems to do what is has to by calling [`File#mkdirs()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29):

```
public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException
{

    // Need to build a URLClassloader since Maven removed it form the chain
    ClassLoader parent = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    String originalSystemClasspath = this.initClassLoader( parent );

    try
    {

        sourceDestDir.mkdirs();
        getDestDir().mkdirs();
        File[] wsdls = getWSDLFiles();
        if(wsdls.length == 0 && (wsdlUrls == null || wsdlUrls.size() ==0)){
            getLog().info( "No WSDLs are found to process, Specify atleast one of the following parameters: wsdlFiles, wsdlDirectory or wsdlUrls.");
            return;
        }
        ...
     }
     ...
}
```

Could you show how you invoke the plugin and its configuration?

Comment: I was executing wsimport using exec-maven-plugin and this was the problem. I switched to jaxws-maven-plugin and now it works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe except compiling sources after processing each WSDL in generate-sources phase. I can't pass -Xnocompile argument to wsimport but it works anyway.

Comment: @Lorean Not sure but 1. you should be able to declare optional wsimport commnd-line options using the `args` optional parameter 2.  it seems the plugin is passing -Xnocompile by default.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `add source` goal of the [**build helper plugin**](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-source</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>${basedir}/target/generated/src/wsimport</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (and is not necessary)

Comment: But is helpful for those who have similar problems.