# IntelliJ Idea generated source

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Just new to IntelliJ Idea. I have maven project which has few generated source java files.
When I import that project Idea complaints about generated source files are missing but I can see those files under `target/generated-sources`. How can I add those files in the classpath.

Comment: Try this solution, it may resolve your issue.
[click here for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278829/7855267)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can go to `Files > Project Structure` and then choose your module and on the sources tab you can navigate to the `generated-sources` dir and click `Mark as > Sources`:

[image: Mark as sources - IDEA]

Additionally, folder could be assigned to the specific type from the `Project` panel via `mark directory as` context menu.

To have maven do it automatically, look here: [How to create folder for generated sources in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958471/how-to-create-folder-for-generated-sources-in-maven)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Springboot Application.

just follow the step in IntelliJ.

1. Right-click on project folder.
2. Select maven.
3. Generate source and update the project folder